# Using Django Caching with Mod_WSGI

Tags: python, django, performance

Is anyone aware of any issues with Django's caching framework when deployed to Apache/Mod_WSGI?

When testing with the caching framework locally with the dev server, using the profiling middleware and either the FileBasedCache or LocMemCache, Django's very fast. My request time goes from ~0.125 sec to ~0.001 sec. Fantastic.

I deploy the identical code to a remote machine running Apache/Mod_WSGI and my request time goes from ~0.155 sec (before I deployed the change) to ~.400 sec (post deployment). That's right, caching **slowed everything down**.

I've spent hours digging through everything, looking for something I'm missing. I've tried using FileBasedCache with a location on tmpfs, but that also failed to improve performance.

I've monitored the remote machine with top, and it shows no other processes and it has 6GB available memory, so basically Django should have full rein. I love Django, but it's incredibly slow, and so far I've never been able to get the caching framework to make any noticeable impact in a production environment. Is there anything I'm missing?

EDIT: I've also tried memcached, with the same result. I confirmed memcached was running by telneting into it.

Comment: What are you using for caching?  If you're using memcached, and memcached isn't actually running, django won't tell you but will just not do caching.  It might be good to make sure caching is actually happening.

Comment: Are you using prefork or worker MPM for Apache? Are you running mod_wsgi in embedded mode or daemon mode? You could just be running Apache/mod_wsgi with a bad config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed django is slow. But I must say most of the slowness goes from app itself.. django just forces you (bu providing bad examples in docs) to do lazy thing that are slow in production.

First of: try nginx + uwsgi. it is just the best.

To optimize you app: you need to find you what is causing slowness, it can be:

- slow database queries (a lot of queries or just slow queries)
- slow database itself
- slow filesystem (nfs for example)

Try logging request queries and watch iostat or iotop or something like that.

I had this scenario with apache+mod_wsgi: first request from browser was very slow... then a few request from same browser were fast.. then if sat doing nothing for 2 minutes - wgain very slow. I don`t know if that was improperly configured apache if it was shutting down wsgi app and starting for each keepalive request. It just posted me off - I installed nging and with nginx+fgxi all was a lot faster than apache+mod_wsgi.

Comment: Seems like you made the mistake of using embedded mode when you should be using daemon mode of mod_wsgi, preferably with worker MPM. The defaults don't give the best solution. Preloading the Django application also helps. uWSGI would be preloading but mod_wsgi lazily loads. You can get mod_wsgi to preload as well.

Comment: Admittedly, I have a lot of database queries that are slowing things down. However, with caching in place, these should be getting avoided entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an app using memcached. The solution was running mod_wsgi in daemon mode instead of embeded mode, and Apache in mpm_worker mode. After that, application is working much faster.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using mpm_worker mode, but I am pretty sure I'm using mod_wsgi in daemon mode. My sites-enabled file has WSGIDaemonProcess with processes=5 and threads=15.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me and was wondering what is that is taking so much time. 
each cache get was taking around 100 millisecond.

So I debugged the code django locmem code and found out that pickle was taking a lot of time (I was caching a whole table in locmemcache).
I wrapped the locmem as I didn't wanted anything advanced, so even if you remove the pickle and unpickle and put it. You will see a major improvement.

Hope it helps someone.